# How to successfully build for ARM Cortex-M0 using arm-gcc-none-eabi?

Tags: stm32, compiler, cortex-m0

I want to debug the following **source file** to a cortex M0 microcontroller.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "stm32f042x6.h"
#include "core_cm0.h"


#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

uint32_t BIT1 = 1;
const char OK_MESSAGE[] = "OK";
const char ACK_MESSAGE[] = "ACK";

volatile char g_buffer_uart_rx[BUFFER_SIZE];

uint8_t g_rx_position = 0;
uint8_t g_tx_position = 0;



//pins A10 and A11 set to AF (UART rx and tx)
void ConfigPinAF()
{
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;

    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER10_1 + GPIO_MODER_MODER9_1;
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL9_Msk + GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL10_Msk;
}


void SetUARTInterruption()
{
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 2);

    // transmission complete and  reception interruptions enabled.
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE + USART_CR1_RXNEIE;
}

void ConfigureUART()
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;

    // Word length set to default value: 8 data bits, n stop bits

    /*
        for oversampling == 16: USARTDIV = fclk/(baudrate)
        for oversampling == 8: USARTDIV = 2*fclk/(baudrate)
        USARTDIV = 8 000 000/9600
        USARTDIV = 833
    */
    USART1->BRR = 833;

    // stop bits set to default value: 1 stop bit.

    // enable receiver and transmitter
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE + USART_CR1_RE;

    SetUARTInterruption();

    //Enable UART
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;
}

void SendAck()
{
    if(g_tx_position < sizeof(ACK_MESSAGE))
    {
        // automatically clear the transfer interruption flag
        for(uint8_t index = 0; index < sizeof(uint8_t); index++)
        {
            USART1->TDR = 0;
            USART1->TDR |= ACK_MESSAGE[g_tx_position] & (BIT1 << index);
        }
        g_tx_position++;
    }
    else
    {
        g_tx_position = 0;
    }
}

void USART1_IRQHandler()
{
    // rx interrupt
    if(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)
    {
        g_buffer_uart_rx[g_rx_position] = USART1->RDR;
        g_rx_position++;
    }
    // tx complete interrupt
    else if(USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)
    {
        SendAck();
    }
    else
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    ConfigPinAF();
    ConfigureUART();

    memset((void *) g_buffer_uart_rx, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    while(1)
    {
        if(0 == strcmp((const char *) g_buffer_uart_rx, OK_MESSAGE))
        {
            g_rx_position = 0;
            SendAck();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the **Makefile** used to compile it:

```
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
OC = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
OS = arm-none-eabi-size

TARGET = stepper_driver

MCU_SPEC = cortex-m0

DEVICE = stm32f030x6
LD_SCRIPT = $(DEVICE).ld
COREFLAGS = -mthumb -mcpu=$(MCU_SPEC)


CFLAGS = $(COREFLAGS) -Wall -O0 -fmessage-length=0 $(INCLUDE_PATHS)
ASFLAGS = $(COREFLAGS) -c -O0 -Wall -fmessage-length=0
LFLAGS = $(COREFLAGS) $(SRC_FILE_DEFS) --specs=rdimon.specs -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/\
         -L/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp/\
         -lc -T$(LD_SCRIPT)

SRC_FILE_DEFS = -u Default_Handler

3RD_FILE_PATH = 3rd-src/STM32-libs/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Source/Templates/gcc
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I3rd-src/STM32-libs/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Include -I3rd-src/STM32-libs/Drivers/CMSIS/Include\
                -I/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/include

SRC_DIR = src
OUT_DIR = build
$(shell mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR))

AS_SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.s) $(3RD_FILE_PATH)/startup_$(DEVICE).s
C_SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(3RD_FILE_PATH)/startup_$(DEVICE).s, $(OUT_DIR)/startup_$(DEVICE).o, $(AS_SRC))\
       $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OUT_DIR)/%.o, $(C_SRC))

$(info $(LFLAGS))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUT_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o: $(AS_SRC)
    $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OUT_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ $(LFLAGS) -o  $@

$(OUT_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin: $(OUT_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf
    $(OC) -S -O binary $(OUT_DIR)/$< $@
    $(OS) $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)/*
```

and the **linker script**

```
ENTRY (Reset_Handler)

/*  initial stack pointer value
    It points to the end of the RAM memory
*/
_estack = 0x200017FF;

/* Memory spaced dedicated to SRAM and HEAP memory */
_Min_Leftover_RAM = 0x400;



MEMORY
{
    FLASH ( rx ) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 16K
    RAM ( rw ) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 6K
}

SECTIONS
{
    /* . = location counter, específica o endereço inicial que o script de linking está montando */
    /* A seção vector_table será posicionada no endereço 0x0800 0000 -  início da memória flash*/
    .vector_table :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.vector_table))
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH


    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)
        *(.text*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH

    .rodata :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rodata*)
        . = ALIGN(4);

    } >FLASH

    _sidata = .;
    .data :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        /* Mark start/end locatin for the 'data' section. */
        _sdata = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > RAM

    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;
    } > RAM

    .dynamic_allocations :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ssystem_ram = .;
        . = . + _Min_Leftover_RAM;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _esystem_ram = .;
    } > RAM
}
```

when I run make, the following errors appear:

```
-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -u Default_Handler --specs=rdimon.specs -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/ -L/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp/ -lc -Tstm32f030x6.ld
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -c -O0 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 3rd-src/STM32-libs/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32f030x6.s -o build/startup_stm32f030x6.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -c -O0 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 3rd-src/STM32-libs/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32f030x6.s -o build/test.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/startup_stm32f030x6.o build/test.o -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m0 -u Default_Handler --specs=rdimon.specs -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/ -L/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp/ -lc -Tstm32f030x6.ld -o  build/stepper_driver.elf
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: build/test.o:(.isr_vector+0x0): multiple definition of `g_pfnVectors'; build/startup_stm32f030x6.o:(.isr_vector+0x0): first defined here
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: build/test.o: in function `Default_Handler':
(.text.Default_Handler+0x0): multiple definition of `Default_Handler'; build/startup_stm32f030x6.o:(.text.Default_Handler+0x0): first defined here
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp/rdimon-crt0.o: in function `_mainCRTStartup':
(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `main'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: (.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `__bss_start__'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: (.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `__bss_end__'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: (.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `__end__'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: build/startup_stm32f030x6.o: in function `LoopFillZerobss':
(.text.Reset_Handler+0x2a): undefined reference to `SystemInit'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: (.text.Reset_Handler+0x32): undefined reference to `main'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: build/test.o: in function `LoopFillZerobss':
(.text.Reset_Handler+0x2a): undefined reference to `SystemInit'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: (.text.Reset_Handler+0x32): undefined reference to `main'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp//librdimon.a(rdimon-syscalls.o): in function `_sbrk':
syscalls.c:(.text._sbrk+0x48): undefined reference to `end'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:58: build/stepper_driver.elf] Error 1
```

Apparently, there are two types of erros:

- Duplicated definition of some symbols: "Default_Handler" and "g_pfnVectors", for instance;
- undefined functions: `` undefined reference to `SystemInit' ``

The first one seems to happen because the listed symbols are defined in libc and in the startup file "startup_stm32f030x6.s" (I got it from [stm32 github](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF0/blob/master/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32f030x6.s))
If I omit `$(patsubst $(3RD_FILE_PATH)/startup_$(DEVICE).s, $(OUT_DIR)/startup_$(DEVICE).o, $(AS_SRC))\` from OBJS definition, these erros vanish, but I think the startup file that will be used is the generic one defined by libc.

**First question (error type one)**

I would like to use the startup file defined by stm32 and the string functions from libc.

How can I link them without the duplicate definition errors?

**Second question (error type two)**

The undefined functions are called by startup_stm32f030x6.s.

what is/are the file(s) that define(s) the functions? Or should I define them?

Comment: You could use a common IDE like https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm-studio-stm32.html . By creating a "Empty project" you can build your code upon a working environment.

Comment: Agree with ElectronicsStudent - if you're new to this then use "easy mode" first. An IDE like STM32CubeIDE will create a buildable project for you to just drop your code into. It'll include all the correct system files for your micro, choose the correct linker script, and just generally make your life easier. It'll build with the same GCC compiler & linker you're currently trying to use in "hard mode", but it'll probably just work.

Comment: If you realy don't want to use CubeIDE, at least, pick a full working project, that you can modify to your needs. It'll be a much shorter way than trying to assemble a new project from scratch, using files from different sources. BTW CubeIDE generates makefiles, you can use them to build a project using regular make, without the IDE.